# SSRS with MVC 5

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I am new in web application. I just want to know if the ssrs or SQL SERVER REPORTING SERVICES is possible in the web applications that using asp.net MVC 5. I just want to create reports in my web application.

Answer (score 0):

Yah it's possible i have used in MVC 4 so its possible in MVC 5 as well.

For that you need to Install Business Intelligence for Visual Studio.

Check Below link for more details:

[Create Step by Step SSRS reports with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/35fef0/creating-report-server-project-in-business-intelligence-deve/)

Comment: thanks. I download the data tools in visual studio 2013 and my question is where i can open the ssrs in visual studio 2013?

Comment: Please check above link for create your first report in **ASP.Net MVC**

Comment: I do not believe that your SSRS server can be accessed via Visual Studio however you can deploy rdl, rds etc via Visual Studio

Comment: For SSRS deployment you have to check this link : https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/sql-server-reporting-services-basics-deploying-reports/